# Building App in Xamarin Studio using a Mac wont show string in a correct way (language = pt-BR)

Tags: c#, ios, macos, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have an application that has lots of strings created in the code behind. There is, it is dinamically and cant be hard coded on the storyboard xml...

When I build this app in Visual Studio, it is ok. But when I build it on Xamarion Studio in a Mac, it replaces the special characters I have from pt-BR to weird symbols.

I have already changed the main OS language and the problem still happens...

Any clue?

Thank you in advance.